# Domain redirecting to my site without permission

Tags: ip, domain

I noticed that a domain that I don't own or know has been redirected to my site without my permission and has been affecting my SEO. I was able to block some of it by adding the following to the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} badsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

However, the homepage still shows up. Is there another way I can completely block it?

Comment: How is the domain redirected? DNS or some script or header?

Comment: If they're redirecting the client to your server, you can require HTTPS (SSL/TLS) as well as configure your server to only accept requests that specify your own domains.

Comment: @villican It seems to be redirected by DNS.

Answer (score 3):

**Contact the registrar that the domain is registered with.**

You can use any WHOIS search engine to gain the abuse contact details for the registrar, *as well as* (providing that they haven't made the WHOIS data private) the owner's contact details. I often use the [who.is](https://who.is) search for WHOIS information (I find that there are a few 'WHOIS search' providers out there who are actually registrars).

The section you'll be interested in is this:

```
Domain Name: EXAMPLE.COM
Registry Domain ID: 000000_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN 
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.register.it 
Registrar URL: http://we.register.it 
Updated Date: 2015-08-20T00:00:00Z 
Creation Date: 2015-05-20T00:00:00Z 
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2016-05-20T00:00:00Z 
Registrar: REGISTER.IT S.P.A. 
Registrar IANA ID: 168 
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abuse[at]register.it 
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +39.0353230310
```

Obviously the registrar's information will vary from domain to domain, but you'll still be wanting to know this info:

- `Registrar Registration Expiration Date` - If the domain is expiring inside a month, I personally wouldn't bother reporting it *unless* you feel it is doing you serious harm or that the domain's expiration date is extended (the owner will probably get notifications that it's expiring a couple of weeks prior)
- `Registrar Abuse Contact Email/Phone`- Here's where to contact to have the domain investigated for abuse (*this includes purporting to be another website, which is the case here*). If successful, the domain will be suspended.

You will also be interested in the `Registry Tech ID:` section of the WHOIS record, which lists additional details for the registrar. Depending on whether the registrar is a reseller, this information could be different to the information mentioned above.

If you *still* can't get hold of the registrar, [contact](https://www.icann.org/) ICANN directly (if it's a domain regulated by them), or the appropriate regulator for the TLD or SLD of the offending website. If the registrar won't do anything about it/can't contact they ***the regulator will***.

Comment: I already tried WHOIS, found a number and called it. It's been disconnected. I also emailed and no answer. The information seem fake.

Comment: @user3380039 Updated answer.